# Accessing fields, methods of Java classes that aren't imported in Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm starting to get more into Clojure-Java interop.  If I create a Java class in Clojure, I need to import it, but if I merely use fields or methods of a class, I don't have to import it. For example:

```
(ns students.Student
  (:import [sim.util Double2D])

(defn -step
  [this students]  ; students is a students.Students, extends sim.engine.SimState
  (let [yard (.-yard students) ; a sim.field.continuous.Continuous2D
        yard-width (.-width yard)
        yard-height (.-height yard)]
    (.setObjectLocation yard this (Double2D. (/ yard-height 2) (/ yard-width 2)))))
```

This won't compile without importing `Double2D`, because the code creates a `Double2D` instance.

However, the fact that I access the `yard` field and `setObjectLocation()` method of a `Students` instance, and the `width` and `height` fields of a `Continuous2D` instance causes no problems, even though I don't import the `Students` or `Continuous2D` classes.

Does this mean that Clojure is using reflection at runtime to access Java fields and methods?  Is that inefficient?  If I need speed in a function, could it be advantageous to add type declarations for the Java classes, along the missing import statements?  Would that prevent reflection?

[EDIT: As my second comment on Arthur Ulfeldt's answer suggests, I now think that any inefficiencies that come from not knowing classes at compile time are likely to be not very different from inefficiencies that come from the fact that functions are contained in variables.  If I was worried about *that*, I'd forget about Clojure and program in pure Java (*maybe*), instead of trying to use Java libs from Clojure.  For me, a world in which I can use Clojure instead of Java is a better one.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Import is only used to make it so [you don't have to type the full name of the class](http://www.braveclojure.com/java/), including it's package name, each time you want to use it. **if a class is on the classpath you can call it by it's full name from anywhere**. If you as an import statement you can call it by just the class name, though only from within the namespace where that import exists.

I'll start with a new project and add a dependency that is clearly *not* used anywhere in the default project, in this case the Riemann client for monitoring stuff (it's a great program check it out)

```
lein new hello
```

and add the dep

```
(defproject hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :aot :all
  :main hello.core
  :profiles {:uberjar {:aot :all}}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [com.aphyr/riemann-java-client "0.3.1"]])
```

then first thing, I'll look at that class by it's full name without any import

```
hello.core> com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
```

then try the short name:

```
hello.core> RiemannClient
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: RiemannClient in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init3055907211270530213.clj:1:5933)
```

which does not work:

```
hello.core> (import '[com.aphyr.riemann.client RiemannClient])
com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
```

Then if we add the import and try again:

```
hello.core> RiemannClient
com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
```

the name resolves from within the user namespace.
If I change namespaces:

```
hello.core> (in-ns 'foo)
```

and then look at the class again:

```
foo> RiemannClient
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: RiemannClient in this context, compiling:(/tmp/form-init3055907211270530213.clj:1:5933) 
foo> com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
com.aphyr.riemann.client.RiemannClient
```

we can see that imports are per-namespace, though classes on the classpath are available everywhere.

Comment: Thanks--that's very helpful. I didn't realize all of that about Java classes.  I'm still wondering about accessing methods and fields of an undeclared Java class.  Checking the type of a Clojure built-in means dealing with one of a known range of possible types, and it's my understanding that in some cases, the compiler is able to determine the types in advance.  But when applying `.-x` or `.setObjectLocation` to the `yard` object, for example, the compiler doesn't even know what functions these are until runtime.  This seems more difficult than dealing with dynamic typing involving built-ins.

Comment: Oh, wait.  I'm talking about a functional language.  [slaps side of head] Clojure doesn't necessarily know what function *any* name refers to, at compile time.  [I can write `(def inc dec)`, but so what?  Power and beauty have risks.]  So not knowing what `.setObjectLocation` means is nothing special.

Comment: It helps with this sort of meditation if you focus on the fact that the unit of compilation is the top level s-expression. Def updates the root values of vars in a namespace which is not a persistent data structure. It really does update in place, and the values of function are known at compile time, where compile time is for *that* expression. redefining a var does not change functions out from under already compiled code. This is fundamentally because the unit of compilation is a single expression. If you want functions to change out from under your code call vars explicitly `(#'inc 4)`

Comment: Ah, right.  I see.  Thanks.  But the compiler still doesn't know what function is in a lexical variable or, for example, what function a higher-order function will produce.  The fact that it doesn't know what members are contained in a Java instance that will be the value of a lexical variable seems similar.